# Does difficulty of locks and computers scale with your level in DLC?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've read that although there is a recomended level range för DLC, you can to some extent enter whenever you like. I personally have done them at roughly ten levels higher than what the wikia says.

My next walkthrough I was thinking of gentering at a lower level, but that also means my Lockpick and Science will be lower. Will the difficulty of locks and computers stay the same or are they adjusted with my level?

Comment: The level recommendation is because the baddies are pretty tough in the DLC, and will squish lower level players much more quickly.

Comment: I've noticed that, even being overleveled, it can be rather easy to die even if technically overleveled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lockpick requirements do not scale with your level, in DLC or otherwise.  There's a list of all the locks on [this page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lock) which gives the fixed lockpick requirements for each.

Science and terminals are a bit trickier - the Wikia lists a range for [some terminals](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Terminal) although it's not clear to me what this indicates.  I believe that they've just consolidated all the terminals in a particular area on a single row, and that the Science requirements are fixed.

Most other skill checks in the game (in dialog or otherwise) do not scale with your level.